# Finding the conditional probability of two dependent events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

I knew there are lots of similar probability problems. However when the questions vary a bit, I got confused about the concepts. For example, I understand the concept of conditional probability between two dependent variables but I don't know how to interpret the following situation:

Given: 
$$X = binomial(n,p)$$
$$Y = binomial(m,p)$$
$$Z = X+Y$$
$$p_X(X=i) = {n \choose i} \cdot p^i \cdot (1-p)^{n-i}$$
$$p_Y(X=j) = {n \choose j} \cdot p^j \cdot (1-p)^{n-j}$$

I found that: 
$$\because Z = X+Y$$
$$\therefore Z=z = i+j$$
$$p_Z(X,Y) = {n+m \choose z} \cdot p^z \cdot (1-p)^{n+m-z}$$

How do I find: $$Pr(Z=12|X=10)$$
My approach: 
$$Pr(Z|X)=\dfrac{Pr(Z(X=10,Y=2))Pr(X=10))}{Pr(X=10)}$$
in which the Pr(X=10) can be dropped but I don't know how to proceed to next step. 
Also, is the following approach correct?
$$\because Pr(B|A)=\dfrac{Pr(A \cap B)}{Pr(A)}$$
$$\therefore Pr(Z|X)=\dfrac{Pr(Z=12,X=10)}{Pr(X=10)}$$
by substituting the given value into the pmf of $p_z$ and $p_x$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X+Y=z\mid X=x)~&=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(Y=z-X, X=x)}{\mathsf P(X=x)}
\\[2ex]&=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(Y=z-x, X=x)}{\mathsf P(X=x)}
\\[2ex]&=~\mathsf P(Y=z-x\mid X=x)
\\[4ex]\therefore\qquad\mathsf P(Z=12\mid X=10)~&=~\mathsf P(Y=2\mid X=10)\end{align}$

Now consider that $X,Y$ are independent, so...

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yet, I have difficulty understanding the intuition of this manipulation. If I substitute Z with Y, am I still obtaining the same result as Z conditioned on X?

Comment: @Jim: You're not substituting $Z$ with $Y$. In the upper equation you're substituting the given value $x$ of $X$ for $X$, then bringing it to the right-hand side. In the lower equation you're merely using the definition $Z:=X+Y$ and instantiating $x$ and $z$ with their given values $10$ and $12$, respectively.

Comment: Exactly. The event of $\{X+Y=12, X=10\}$ *is* the event of $\{Y=2, X=10\}$.  I've added a few steps to hopefully make things clearer. @Jim

Comment: Not sure if I should use comment to thank people, but thank you for helping me out.